# How to remove an object in a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

Let me explain.

I got this JSON with many objects: 
`data = [{"id":"784","label":"blah","publisher":"me"},{"id":"785","label":"bleh","publisher":"you"},{"id":"786","label":"blih","publisher":"she"}];`

Ex: I want to remove the object where id = 785

I tried:

```
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
if(value.id == '785'){
    delete data[key];
}
});
```

It works, but it changes 'data' structure. Now it seems like this:

```
data = ["0":{"id":"784","label":"blah","publisher":"me"},"2":{"id":"786","label":"blih","publisher":"she"}]
```

I'm working  with a plugin that does not accept this structure(jQuery UI Autocomplete). So I need to remove the object without changing the 'data' structure.

Any help?

Comment: rather than `delete`, just remove it as if you were removing an array value (because that's what you're doing)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Which jQuery version?

Comment: This question appears to be based on invalid assumptions as the problem is not reproductible.

Comment: jquery 1.10.2, UI 1.10.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to do it is using filter on the array:

```
var data = [{"id":"784","label":"blah","publisher":"me"},{"id":"785","label":"bleh","publisher":"you"},{"id":"786","label":"blih","publisher":"she"}];

var result = data.filter(function(x){return x.id !== '785'; });
```

HTH

Comment: This is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

That's an array of objects, so try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].id == 785) {
        data.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want `data = data.splice(...)`, just `data.splice(...)`. It's a mutator. The value it returns is the thing it *removed*.

Comment: Just saw that, thanks for the edit, was trying to remember if `splice` needed that.

Comment: You should also break after you removed the element. I'm assuming there will not be any other object with id `785`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U94Ym/1/):

```
var i = 0;
while (i < data.length) {
    if (data[i].id === "785") {
        data.splice(i, 1)
    }
    else {
        i++;
    }
}
```